# How to call programmatic log4j2 configuration update, before calling to LoggerFactory.getLogger(${className})

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j2

I want to updateLoggres or reconfigure the log4j2 configuration before calling to the LoggerFactory.getLogger(${className}) (i.e this is slf4j api).

```java
   public void addAppender() {
        LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext();
        Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();

        PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder()
          .withConfiguration(config)
          .withPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %msg%n")
          .build();


        RollingFileAppender appender = RollingFileAppender.newBuilder()
          .setConfiguration(config)
          .withName("TestAppender")
          .withLayout(layout)
          .withFileName("logs/TestAppenderlog")
          .withFilePattern("Zuzi")
          .withPolicy(SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy("10KB"))
          .build();

        appender.start();
        config.addAppender(appender);
        
        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig("TestAppender") ;
        loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);

        ctx.updateLoggers();
    }
```

So here I want to call this addAppender() method in my java spring application, What is the ideal place to call this method.
Ex: **Is it in contextInitialized() method or any other suggestions?**

Comment: Is this just Spring-MVC or Spring Boot?

Comment: It is Spring-MVC